# Which formula will calculate values shown in this graph?

Tags: functions, approximation-theory

First, sorry about a n00b question.

Here's the graph:

[image]

The x=30, y=0.5 is an approximation. The other two dots are measured. My goal is to mathematically describe/calculate `y` based on arbitrary `x` value.

**Context**

I'm regulating heating with Raspberry Pi and I have noticed that, to get increase of 1 deg C, the heating needs to work for 1/2 hours when the outside-inside temperature difference is ~10 deg. C. The measured time needed to increase room temp for 1 deg C rises to 1 hour when the in-out diff is 20 deg C. (And, as I said, 30 deg delta is approximated, for now).

The `heating_speed` (y axis, measured in `C/h`) as function of `temp_delta` (x axis, measured in `C`) just "feels" that it can not be linear. But, I could be mistaken.

Additionally, I'm not interrested in the freaky border cases when the in-out temp delta is > 40 C. In those cases, I believe, the current heating power will not be sufficient to keep the temperature stabile and it will probably have negative `heating_speed`.

**Alternate assumption**

Possibly, the function is linear, like this (blue):

[image]

In this case, I guess, the formula will be this: `3.-0.1 x`.
WA [link 1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=linear%20fit%20%7B10,%202.0%7D,%7B20,%201.0%7D&x=4&y=10), [link 2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3.-0.1%20x&lk=1&a=ClashPrefs_*Math-).

Comment: There is an infinite number of functions which could go through your two points. You must decide first on the type of formula you want to use, then compute its parameters and then extrapolate or interpolate for any arbirary value of x.

Comment: @Saran Please provide some context so we can better help you. How did you encounter this?

Comment: @GitGud I've added some "context".

Comment: @Saran [Lagrange's Interpolating Polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) might help you. I don't know anything about physics so I can't promise it will be a good approximation to what you want, but it will yield a polynomial that goes through the points in the graph.

Comment: [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolating+polynomial+%7B10%2C2%7D%2C%7B20%2C1%7D%2C%7B30%2C0.5%7D)'s a WA link.

Comment: @GitGud well, I was looking for something simpler, like `f(x) = 20/x` (wich a friend of mine suggested). That produces value of 2/3 for x=30, which seems sensible.

Comment: @GitGud. To me the problem is that the third point is not measured but just guessed. So what Saran suggests is one way.

Comment: If you would plot instead $y = \mbox{temp_delta}$ and $x = \mbox{h} = t = $ heating time, then doesn't the graph become an exponential function, like $exp(-t/\tau)$ with $\tau$ a decay time ? Such exponentials are rather common with heating problems, in my experience. Moreover, a few measurements would then enable you to determine the function. In general, it's advisable to develop a mathematical model (with some free parameters) of the phenomenon, instead of trying to adapt to a ("randomly chosen") curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use what suggests Han de Bruijn, that is to say y = a Exp[-b x], since you have two data points, you can easily solve for "a" and "b". What you get is a = 4 and b = - Log[2]/10. For x = 30, you exactly get y = 0.5.

Comment: The curve could also be like $1-exp(-t/\tau)$ ; can't get a clear picture from the available information.

Comment: I'd like to accept your answer, but I can't confirm it. I tried with x = 30 and I get y = 0.29.
Log(2)/10 = 0.0301. Times 30 = 0.9031. So, 4 Exp [- 0.9] = 0.29.

Comment: @Saran. It is not a decimal logarithm !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici indeed. But, have you tried calculating other values (apart for x=30)? For example, for x=10, I get y=0.38 which is not even close.

Comment: @Saran. This function was built basd on your two data points. Then, by definition, it is exact at these two points. If y(x) = 4 Exp[- Log(10) x / 10 ], with Log(10) = 2.30259, you have y(0)=4, y(10)=2, y(20)=1, y(30)=0.5, y(40)=0.25, y(50)=0.125. I hope you see the geometric progression for values which are multiples of 10.

Comment: @Saran. I have typos in my previous comment. Sorry for that. You must read Log[2] instead of Log[10] and Log[2]=0.693147. All the remaining is correct.